# Representation of closed linear span of an orthonormal set in Hilbert space

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthonormal

This is a follow-up of this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2339000/closed-linear-span-of-an-arbitrarily-indexed-orthonormal-set-in-hilbert-space).

Here is the statement we want to prove.

> Let $\{x_j\}$ be an arbitrarily indexed orthonormal set in a Hilbert space(possibly non-separable). Show that the closed linear span of $\{x_j\}$ consists of all vectors of the form:$$x=\sum a_j x_j$$ where the sum converges in the sense of Hilbert space norm and the $a_j$ are complex number so chosen that$$\sum \lvert a_j \rvert^2 < \infty$$ Furthermore:$$\lVert x\rVert^2=\sum \lvert a_j \rvert^2$$ with $a_j=(x,x_j)$. (circular brackets denotes the inner product)

My question is the following. Suppose that $y\in\overline{\text{span}\{x_j\}}$. Then there exist a sequence $y^{(n)}\in\text{span}\{x_j\}$ such that $y^{(n)} \to y$. Then there exists a countable index set $I$ such that
\begin{align}
y^{(n)} = \sum_{i\in I} a^{(n)}_{i}x_{j_i}
\end{align}
for each $n$. How can I prove that there exists scalars $a_{i}$ such that
\begin{align}
y = \sum_{i\in I} a_{i}x_{j_i}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\sum_{i\in I} |a_{i}|^2 < \infty,
\end{align}
as claimed in an answer?

Comment: Do you know how to prove the result if the set is countably-infinite? Then you only have to show (using Bessels inequality) that the set $I := \{ j \in J:  \langle x_j , y \rangle \neq 0\}$ is countable for any $y$ in the Hilbertspace and then defining $\sum_{j \in J } x_j \langle x_j, y\rangle  := \sum_{i \in I } x_j \langle x_j, y\rangle $ .